# How to change Header in fetch request at no-cors?

Tags: javascript, cors

Send a request to a server and need to send the header 
'Content-Type': 'application/json'

all this is done with fetch, but because of crossdomain have to specify

mode: 'no-cors',

And in this mode, the browser defaults to - 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'

Actually, this is the problem, since 415 error is returned
Here is the entire request code

```
realFetch(url {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(dataUser)
      }).
```

Prompt how to solve this problem? How to force the browser to change headers using fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Setting `no-cors` tells `fetch` that you do not need CORS permission and so will not doing anything that needs permission.

Setting the `Content-Type` header to a value other than one of the three allowed by the HTML `enctype` attribute **requires** permission from the server using CORS.

Since you have told `fetch` not to check for permission, it ignores your instruction to do something normally forbidden.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header/35553666#35553666) has more information about CORS and cross-origin requests.